# MPEG-TS file not consistent start time

Tags: ffmpeg, video, hls

I am trying to figure out, how come my downloaded mpeg-ts file usually starts at 0 but some of them are not. I'm using wowza streaming engine to stream videos on demand and download the ts files later.Im thinking if it has something to do with the source?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming engines may **concatenate** separate .ts inputs to produce a single .ts output file, in which case the capture may have started *in media res*. E.G., you start capture of a sports event *after* the commercials.

In any event, .ts files are often converted to another format, e.g., MPEG, to make viewing easier and more consistent, in which case the starting point should be reset by the converter.